# Azure Data Explorer Create a new column based on 2 columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, string-conversion

I have a table in Azure Data Explorer and I want to have a new string column that is the result of the concatenation of 2 string columns.

In KQL I can do it by using **extend** and **strcat** functions but I want the column to be part of the table data not just a virtual column:

```
TableName
| extend NewCol=strcat(Col1,"separator",Col2)
```

Doing the above will indeed create a new column and the value I want for the column but will not be stored as a new column in the table which is what I want.

Something like this in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName)
```

Comment: Can you add more information to your requirement , is it like : You have a table1 with 2 columns col1,col2 . Your goal is - you want to have a 3rd column to be added to the same table with name col1col2 ?

Comment: @ShivaPatpi I want to do this in KQL: ALTER TABLE Employees ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName)

Answer (score 2):

you can't ingest data into a new column in *existing* records (that were ingested before the column was added to the table).

in order to populate a calculated column *at ingestion time*, you can use an update policy.

see:

- [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)
- [blog post](https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/update-policies.html)